# Python - AttributeError: index

Tags: python, indexing, attributeerror

I am stuck here...

Connecting to t3://localhost:7001 with userid weblogic ...
Successfully connected to Admin Server 'examplesServer' that belongs to domain 'wl_server'.

Warning: An insecure protocol was used to connect to the
server. To ensure on-the-wire security, the SSL port or
Admin port should be used instead.

[MBeanServerInvocationHandler]com.bea:Name=mainWebApp,Type=AppDeployment
ParcelLienData.war
ParcelLienData
P
Problem invoking WLST - Traceback (innermost last):
  File "D:\RM-Share\RM-Scripts\wl_deploy_localhost-WC.py", line 30, in ?
AttributeError: index

My code looks like:

```
import sys 
import getopt
import os

loadProperties(sys.argv[1] +".props")
connect(username,password,adminUrl)

cmd = "awk -F'Name=' '{print $2}' | awk -F',' '{print $1}'"

f = open(r'./applicationsList.txt','r')
#In Above line you can specify the Complete Path of the "applications.txt" as well

print f
for i in range(5):
       line=f.readline()
       line1=line[:-4]
       line2=line1[:1]
       #check if the service or application is already present on the server...
       cd('AppDeployments')
       myapps=cmo.getAppDeployments()
       for dep_file in myapps:
          print depfile
          print line
          print line1
          print line2
          num1=depfile.index(line2)
          print num1
          num2=depfile.index(",", num1)
          print num2
          appName=depfile[num1:num2]
          print appName

          if appName == "line1":
             print Redeploy
          elif appName != "line1":
             print "Not deploying"
             continue
          else:
             print Deploying
```

Please advice, where am I going wrong....

Thanks....

Answer (score 2):

The error tells you that this line:

```
appName=dep_file[num1:num2]
```

Is wrong. Are you sure the `dep_file` object can be indexed with a slice?

Maybe you should call  `getName()` on `dep_name` first?

Comment: Hey, I am very new to python, not sure what you are referring to, I found a piece of code as below, on blog....which I wanted to use and update as per my requirement...please help    >>> line = '<b>(words only):</b><font color= "#0000FF"> BABY MILESTONES</font><br /><br />'
    >>> line.index("B")
    44
    >>> line.index("<", 44) # 44 is the number of chars before BABY MILESTONES
    59
    >>> line[44:59]
    'BABY MILESTONES'

Comment: but it works fine, when i pass the same set of command on commandline

Comment: Hi Eli, Thanks for your suggestion and you are right, I used as mentioned below and got it worked..thanks.

appName=appLine.getName()